# How to make a label show a double in vs 2012 c#

Tags: c#, variables, visual-studio-2012, label, double

I'm making a reaction test and I have a label so when the green button comes up i need the label to start counting in milliseconds. So I made a timer and a class so the code looks like this:

Class code:

```
class Class2
{
    public static int a = 1;
    public static Double b = 0.000;
}
```

Timer code:

```
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WindowsFormsApplication3.Class2.b = WindowsFormsApplication3.Class2.b + 0.001;
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(WindowsFormsApplication3.Class2.b);
    }
```

But i keep getting an error saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'string' "
How do I stop this error?

some people asked for info so here you have it:
the code:

```
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WindowsFormsApplication3.Class2.a = WindowsFormsApplication3.Class2.a + 1;
        if (WindowsFormsApplication3.Class2.a == 8)
        {
            button1.Visible = false;
            button2.Visible = true;
            timer2.Enabled = true;
        }

        {

        }
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WindowsFormsApplication3.Class2.b = WindowsFormsApplication3.Class2.b + 001;
        label1.Text = WindowsFormsApplication3.Class2.b.ToString();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button3.Visible = false;
        button1.Visible = true;
        timer1.Enabled = true;

    }
}
```

}

The Error:

Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'string' line 38 column 27

Comment: What is the line of code on line 38?

Answer (score 0):

Use the double.ToString() method

`label1.Text = WindowsFormsApplication3.Class2.b.ToString();`